# There is no Cellar in /usr/local for brew

Tags: macintosh, homebrew

I have been trying to use brew to install tmux but every time I put in brew install tmux it would tell me:

> Error: Could not create /usr/local/Cellar
>
> Check you have permission to write to /usr/local

I then tried to do it with sudo but it did not work, which I guest would would not seeing that brew does not want to be used with root. I have already made sure that all the files that are in /usr/local belong to me. I can’t change the /usr/local file; it says: “Operation not permitted”. How can I fix this so Cellar can be created and allow me to install stuff using brew?

Update: I totally forgot that this question was up. I ended up fixing it by reinstalling Homebrew. Apparently an important thing had not been install when I first installed it. Don’t know why, but the Xcode stuff that needed to be installed for the command line. So I had to install that when I reinstalled Homebrew.

Comment: The script on brew's [home page](https://brew.sh/) ought to create the Cellar directory and make it owned by you. Did you run it, or did you install brew some other way? If you ran it, were there any error messages?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I can’t remember exactly how I installed it, but I am sure that I installed it the regular way. I updated my question say I found how I fixed it. How to I close this question without deleting it?

Comment: To close the question without deleting it, accept an answer. You can write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by reinstalling Homebrew. Apparently an important thing had not been install when I first installed it. Don’t know why, but the Xcode stuff that needed to be installed for the command line. So I had to install that when I reinstalled Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
```

Also note that [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) is designed to be used from the user account. If you use it with `sudo` something is wrong.